# How to richly style AOR Edit page

Tags: redux-form, admin-on-rest

Have to create an edit Page editing a number of parameters on an instance of a'tale' resource.

However adding any element such as an MUI Card or even a div, is causing the app to freeze in various ways.

These are the approaches I have tried.

1) Adding a card component or placing my elements within a div for styling

```
export const EditorEditTale = (props) => {
  return (
  <Edit {...props} title="Tale Editor">
    <SimpleForm >
      <div>
        <Image />
        <TaleCardHeader props={ props } style={taleCardHeaderStyle.editor} />
      </div>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
  )
};
```

This is causing nothing to render.

Second approach, assuming that the record and basePath arent getting propagated to the children completely. Trying to use component like below.

```
const Input = ({record, basePath}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <LongTextInput source="taleText" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is causing the page to not render with everything in some kind of locking loop with the error - cannot read property touched of undefined.

How should I create a custom Edit page with a complex inputs and styling.

[image: Required design]

UPDATE: Been trying to write a custom form to substitute the SimpleForm component with no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a custom form you can follow these steps:

1. make an exact copy of [SimpleForm](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/form/SimpleForm.js) to your project.
2. rename SimpleForm to what you want.
3. fix all the relative imports.
4. test the new form until it works.

I made a minimum working form based on current master branch's [SimpleForm](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/489dcfbd16ba54e31486f9b17c8d05db9480afaf/src/mui/form/SimpleForm.js)

```
import React, { Children, Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import getDefaultValues from 'admin-on-rest/mui/form/getDefaultValues';
import FormField from 'admin-on-rest/mui/form/FormField';
import Toolbar from 'admin-on-rest/mui/form/Toolbar';

const formStyle = { padding: '0 1em 1em 1em' };

export class PostForm extends Component {
    handleSubmitWithRedirect = (redirect = this.props.redirect) => this.props.handleSubmit(values => this.props.save(values, redirect));

    render() {
        const { children, invalid, record, resource, basePath, submitOnEnter, toolbar } = this.props;
        return (
            <form className="simple-form">
                <Field name="name_of_a_field" component="input" />
                {toolbar && React.cloneElement(toolbar, {
                    handleSubmitWithRedirect: this.handleSubmitWithRedirect,
                    invalid,
                    submitOnEnter,
                })}
            </form>
        );
    }
}

PostForm.propTypes = {
    basePath: PropTypes.string,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    defaultValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.object,
        PropTypes.func,
    ]),
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func, // passed by redux-form
    invalid: PropTypes.bool,
    record: PropTypes.object,
    resource: PropTypes.string,
    redirect: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.bool,
    ]),
    save: PropTypes.func, // the handler defined in the parent, which triggers the REST submission
    submitOnEnter: PropTypes.bool,
    toolbar: PropTypes.element,
    validate: PropTypes.func,
};

PostForm.defaultProps = {
    submitOnEnter: true,
    toolbar: <Toolbar />,
};

const enhance = compose(
    connect((state, props) => ({
        initialValues: getDefaultValues(state, props),
    })),
    reduxForm({
        form: 'record-form',
        enableReinitialize: true,
    }),
);

export default enhance(PostForm);
```

The above code works for AOR's [example](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/tree/489dcfbd16ba54e31486f9b17c8d05db9480afaf/example).

I hope this helps.

(import might be slightly different when you have AOR as npm dependency :

```
import getDefaultValues from 'admin-on-rest/lib/mui/form/getDefaultValues';
import FormField from 'admin-on-rest/lib/mui/form/FormField';
import Toolbar from 'admin-on-rest/lib/mui/form/Toolbar';
```

)

Comment: I have had some success writing a custom form by the end of the day. Will be building on your suggestions. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Documenting my final answer. You have to create a custom Redux Form. You can use AOR Input components straight. They come prewrapped for Redux Form.

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class StyledForm extends Component {
// Newer version of aor needs this function defined and passed to save buttons. All props are being passed by parent List component. 
handleSubmitWithRedirect = (redirect = this.props.redirect) => this.props.handleSubmit(values => this.props.save(values, redirect));

render() {  
const { handleSubmit, invalid, record, resource, basePath } = this.props
return (<div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
      <Card >
        <CardText >

          //This component simply displays data, something not possible very easily with SimpleForm. 
          <HeaderComp basePath={basePath} record={record} />

          <Field source="category_id"
                 optionText="categoryName"
                 reference="categories"
                 resource={resource}
                 record={record}
                 basePath={basePath}
                 name="NAME OF THE FIELD IN YOUR REDUX DATASTORE"
                 component={REFERENCEFIELDCOMP} />
          //create complex div structures now. 
          <div >
            <span>Tale</span>
            <Field resource={resource} record={record} basePath={basePath} name="taleText" component={TextInput} />
          </div>

         </CardText >

          <MuiToolbar>
            <ToolbarGroup>
              <SaveButton handleSubmitWithRedirect={this.handleSubmitWithRedirect}/>
              //Add custom buttons with custom actions
              <Field record={record} name="status" component={EditButtons} />

            </ToolbarGroup>
          </MuiToolbar>
      </Card>
    </form>
  </div>)
    }
};

const enhance = compose(
    connect((state, props) => ({
        initialValues: getDefaultValues(state, props),
    })),
    reduxForm({
        form: 'record-form',
        enableReinitialize: true,
    }),
);

export default enhance(StyledForm);
```

You will have to either import or copy getDefaultValues from AOR in the node modules. 
I copied it into the file below.

```
import getDefaultValues from '../functions/getDefaultValues';
```

If you need a referenceField in your field. Then wrap it in a custom component like shown below

```
const DropDownSelector = ({optionText, ...props}) => {
  return (
      <ReferenceInput {...props} label="" >
        <SelectInput optionText={optionText} />
      </ReferenceInput>
  )
}
```